# TeX outputs slowly to the console

Tags: console

I have TeX live 2022 running on Windows 10. When I compile a file using TeX (3.141592653) it writes to the console (cmd) so SLOWLY character, by character, as if it's trying to emulate a teletype. Is this a feature? Can I change this behaviour?

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! I believe this is not a feature. Possibly some bug.

Comment: Interestingly this issue went away after I re-enabled the the "Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Service" in Windows, although I've not checked to see if it comes back when disabled.